# Narrowing the type of a generic function

Tags: typescript, generics, indexing

Consider the following snippet:

```
function doIt<K extends string>(key: K, arg: number): string {
    return `key=${key}, arg=${arg}`;
}

// [A] Doesn't work, DoIt is no longer a generic!
// type DoIt = typeof doIt;

// I have to duplicate the signature of doIt here:
type DoIt<K extends string> = (key: K, arg: number) => string;

type ITextEntryBlock = {
    [key: string]: { en: string; fr: string };
};

const textMap: ITextEntryBlock = {
    body: {
        fr: 'Bonjour {prefix} {firstname} {lastname}',
        en: 'Dear {prefix} {firstname} {lastname}',
    },
    test: {
        fr: 'FR {prefix} {firstname} {lastname}',
        en: 'EN {prefix} {firstname} {lastname}',
    },
};

// [B] Doesn't work: keyof typeof textMap
type Entries = 'body' | 'test';

const doItNarrowed: DoIt<Entries> = doIt;

console.log(doItNarrowed('body', 42));
console.log(doItNarrowed('test', 7));
// doItNarrowed('blah', 0); // fails, which is good
```

The snippet compiles and works, but has two problems, which I have marked with `[A]` and `[B]`.

`[A]`: When using `typeof` on a generic function, the type apparently loses its generality. `DoIt<Entries>` fails when `DoIt` was declared using `typeof`. This is unfortunate, because every time I change the signature of `doIt` I'll have to update the type `DoIt` as well.

`[B]`: I'd like to declare `type Entries = keyof typeof textMap`. This kind of works, but somehow TypeScript also adds the type `number`, and `DoIt<Entries>` will fail, because `number` does not extend `string`. So I have to explicitly declare `Entries`, which is unfortunate, because every time I add a new key to `textMap` I'll have to update the type `Entries` as well.

Is there a way how to solve these problems?

Comment: Your [B] question is not related to the title or to the [A] question, right? I'd suggest removing it and possibly opening a new question about it.

Comment: The closest you can get programmatically is something awful like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgSSgHgNKIKYAeUeYyAzomVAE4xgDmAfABQDWeAngFyLYA0iAIbV6PMCAC2AIzzUAlDyq0GiAN4AoRFsTU8UENSQADdhwC8AElWmAvgOH1LqhzaMBudTfVQOABzyIAOIkAGLgEIhmiD7+cMAo6FAeEAA2gmQUwWAAKn54ALKC7NSY2fhEJOSUNHRMapra9HpZuf4AhDyYAILlxKQUgmAcANoAugIASiwQUjzMAHSLgjxdcpGMiBNrZhvM27uL88uIq+ubHtqITTl5kdEAFjBk801QLXnM4ikpbUKZoeE5KUWHJPN5bgARRKlXqVChKWobKLvfyFYrA4YAcmurTwmNG6nUQA) (from the duplicate answer). I'd recommend just do it like you're doing it.

Comment: It's not quite correct to say `DoIt` "loses its generality".  It's just that it's a different sort of generic and the language doesn't convert between them for you; see the duplicate answer.  Good luck!